# Groovy - Join filter maps

Tags: groovy

I want to check who can come up with the best Groovy-sh way to achieve this -

```
def m1 = [["id":"1","o":"11"],["id":"1","o":"12"],["id":"2","o":"21"]]
def m2 = [["o":"11","t":"t1"],["o":"11","t":"t2"],["o":"21","t":"t1"]]
```

I want result

```
[["id":"1","t":"t1"],["id":"1","t":"t2"],["id":"2","t":"t1"]]
```

I'm currently iterating the maps and doing this. I'm looking for a solution using Gpath and findAll

Thanks,
Sreehari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `transpose` both lists and get the entry (`id` or `t`) from each list:

```
def fn = { m1, m2 ->
    return [m1,m2]
        .transpose()
        .collect { [ id: it.first().id, t: it.last().t ] }
}


def m1 = [["id":"1","o":"11"],["id":"1","o":"12"],["id":"2","o":"21"]]
def m2 = [["o":"11","t":"t1"],["o":"11","t":"t2"],["o":"21","t":"t1"]]


assert fn(m1, m2) == 
        [["id":"1","t":"t1"],["id":"1","t":"t2"],["id":"2","t":"t1"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transpose to zip the maps into pairs, then combine the pairs and filter by map key:

```
[m1, m2]
    .transpose()
    .collect { (it[0] + it[1]).subMap(['id', 't']) }
```

which evaluates to

```
[[id:1, t:t1], [id:1, t:t2], [id:2, t:t1]]
```

This works in groovysh using groovy-2.4.4, with either jdk7 or jdk8.

Comment: @sreehari: it filters the map by key: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-getting-submap-from-map.html

Comment: I cannot accept this as an answer as it does no compile and produce the desired results as stated above.

Comment: @sreehari: you have every right to select whichever answer suits you, but your above comment seems inaccurate. maybe you need to specify how you need to execute this more clearly.